# How to Fetch realm database results in getView method

Tags: android

I am working on an Android app, I am using realm database. I have custom layout for listview which contain an ImageView, Title, Tag, Description. I stored data in realm using realm.beginTransaction(), I am facing difficulty how can i call these data in getView method of BaseAdapter (Custom ListView).

This is my code of RealmObject

```
public class Ads extends RealmObject {

@PrimaryKey
private String adId;
private String adTitle;
private String adTags;
private String adDescription;
private String adImages;


public Ads() {


}

public String getAdId() {
    return adId;
}

public void setAdId(String adId) {
    this.adId = adId;
}

public String getAdTitle() {
    return adTitle;
}

public void setAdTitle(String adTitle) {
    this.adTitle = adTitle;
}

public String getAdTags() {
    return adTags;
}

public void setAdTags(String adTags) {
    this.adTags = adTags;
}

public String getAdDescription() {
    return adDescription;
}

public void setAdDescription(String adDescription) {
    this.adDescription = adDescription;
}

public String getAdImages() {
    return adImages;
}

public void setAdImages(String adImages) {
    this.adImages = adImages;
}
```

}

That is how i am storing data in Activity

```
       try {

                        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

                        realm.beginTransaction();
                        Ads newAd = realm.createObject(Ads.class);
                        newAd.setAdId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                        newAd.setAdTitle(_txt_postTitle.getText().toString());
                        newAd.setAdTags("Android|Facebook|ChatHead");
                        newAd.setAdDescription(_txt_postDesc.getText().toString());
                        newAd.setAdImages(ImageString);
                        realm.commitTransaction();


                        Toast.makeText(TimeLineActivity.this, "Post Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } catch (Exception ex) {

                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Now Question come here that, how can i get these data and use it into BaseAdaper in getView method.

```
 @Override
public View getView(int i, View convertview, ViewGroup viewGroup) {


    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertview == null) {

        convertview =inflater.inflate(R.layout.timeline_row_item,null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();


        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();



        holder._imgProfilePic = (ImageView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.img_profile_pic);
        holder._bigImage = (ImageView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.big_image);
        holder._small_Image_a = (ImageView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.small_image_a);
        holder._small_Image_b = (ImageView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.small_image_b);
        holder._small_Image_c = (ImageView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.small_image_c);
        holder._postTitle = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.txt_post_title);
        holder._postTagLine = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.txt_post_tagline);
        holder._postedOn = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.txt_posted_on);
        holder._postDescription = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.txt_post_description);
        holder._postPlusMore = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.txt_plus_more);

        convertview.setTag(holder);

    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertview.getTag();
    }


    RealmResults<Ads> ads = realm.allObjects(Ads.class);
    //Here Like 
    // Like holder._postTitle(getTitle From Realm Stored Data)



    return convertview;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate the layers. Querying a query and projection of the some data isn't the same process. Fetch your data into DAO or db access layer, get it and set the results as source list to your custom listview.